# How to UICollectionReusableView stretch to Safe Area

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am trying to show HeaderView in my UICollectionView class and I use UICollectionReusableView class for that.

Actually I am showing HeaderView in my CollectionView but It does not reach to safe area.

I use auto layout programmatically and I wrote extension to do that.

Here is my class and extensions that I use in my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

private let headerIdentifer = "HeaderCell"

class ProfileController: UICollectionViewController { 
    //MARK: - Properties
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureProfileCollectionView()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        
    }

    //MARK: - Helpers

    func configureProfileCollectionView() {
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.register(HeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifer)
    }
}

extension ProfileController {
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifer, for: indexPath) as! HeaderView
        return header
    }
}

extension ProfileController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 300)
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class HeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    
    private lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        view.addSubview(backButton)
        backButton.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor,
                          paddingTop: 42, paddingLeft: 16)
        backButton.setDimensions(width: 30, height: 30)
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var backButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "baseline_arrow_back_white_24dp")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    
    //MARK: - Lifecyle
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, right: rightAnchor, height: 108)
            
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    //MARK: - Selectors
    
    @objc func backButtonTapped() {
        
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil,
                left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil,
                bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil,
                right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil,
                paddingTop: CGFloat = 0,
                paddingLeft: CGFloat = 0,
                paddingBottom: CGFloat = 0,
                paddingRight: CGFloat = 0,
                width: CGFloat? = nil,
                height: CGFloat? = nil) {
        
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let left = left {
            leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let right = right {
            rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let width = width {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let height = height {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        }
    }
    
    func center(inView view: UIView, yConstant: CGFloat? = 0) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: yConstant!).isActive = true
    }
    
    func centerX(inView view: UIView, topAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, paddingTop: CGFloat? = 0) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        if let topAnchor = topAnchor {
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: paddingTop!).isActive = true
        }
    }
    
    func centerY(inView view: UIView, leftAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, paddingLeft: CGFloat? = nil, constant: CGFloat? = 0) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: constant!).isActive = true
        
        if let leftAnchor = leftAnchor, let padding = paddingLeft {
            self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
        }
    }
    
    func setDimensions(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
    }
    
    func addConstraintsToFillView(_ view: UIView) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor,
               bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)
    }
    
    
}
```

[image: How HeaderView looks in the simulator]

Comment: Try adding these at viewDidLoad: `edgesForExtendedLayout = [.top]; view.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `UICollectionReusableView` is set up fine I believe and I think an automatic inset is applied to the `UICollectionView` because of the safe area.

Try **one of the two options below** in your `viewDidLoad` and it might work

```
// Option 1
// Get the inset applied at the top and negate the applied inset
if let top
    = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top
{
    collectionView.contentInset.top = -top
}

// Option 2
// Request the collection view to ignore the default behavior
// to add an inset for safe area
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

[image: UICollectionView ignore safe area insets header content under status bar UICollectionReusableView]

Comment: Thank you Shawn, I tried your Option 2 solution and It worked perfectly. Also Option 1 solution works too.

Comment: Option 2 works on iOS 15.6.2
Option 1 throws "'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead"

Comment: Both Option 1 and Option 2 works fine with me thanks.

Comment: I found this answer after wasting 1.5 hours. Thank you so much, Shawn.

Answer (score 0):

More simple solution. No need to write any code!!!

[image]