# Swift - Layout problem with scrollview and safe area

Tags: swift, layout, uiscrollview, xcode-storyboard, safearealayoutguide

I have a problem with a scrollable layout
I have two UiViewController :

One on the top with a green background (TopVC) and the other is red (the initial VC) which are perfectly scrollable

When I start the app, I have this layout problem : I see the bottom of the other VC(the green one).

[image]

When I start to scroll, this layout problem dissapear and I can scroll up and down without any layout problem.( as you can see the SafeAreaView covers the entire screen as expected )

**Does someone know how I can fix that in order to start with a correct layout ?**

Thanks

For info, the project that I have tested :([link of the github project](https://github.com/jakespracher/Snapchat-Swipe-View))

[image]

Fixed with :

```
if let top
        = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top
    {
        scrollView.contentInset.top = -top
    }
```

Comment: It could be an automatic inset that I noticed in another question, does this answer help you in anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71044943/1619193

Comment: Yes, indeed , for perfect correction it is fixed with :      if let top
            = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top
        {
            scrollView.contentInset.top = -top
        }